# Get data from tables which are in relations

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am writing simple blog with CodeIgniter and DataMapper and I have problem with relation. How can I get posts by particularly tags with DattaMapper. SQL query will be something like that:

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.title,
    posts.content,
    posts.created,
    tags.name 
FROM 
    posts, 
    posts_tags, 
    tags
WHERE 
    posts.id = posts_tags.post_id AND 
    posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id AND
    tag.name = 'php';
ORDER BY
    posts.created DESC;
```

php code:

```
<?php
class Post extends DataMapper 
{
    public $has_many = array('tag');

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getPostsByTags($name, $offset)
    {
        // this doesn't work
        // $this->get_where(array('tags.name', $name), 3, $offset);
    }
}

class Tag extends DataMapper
{
    public $has_many = array('post');

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Database scheme:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the [docu](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/gettingstarted.html) and think this could work:

```
$this->post->get();
foreach ($this->post $post)
{
    foreach ($post->tag->get() as $tag)
    { ... }
}
```

Looks greate. I should give it try myself...

**Update**, [read here](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getby.html):

```
$p = new Post();
// Get users that are related to the Moderator group
$p->where_related_tag('name', 'php')->get();
```

Comment: But in this solution I get all posts and then check which post has preferred tag name. So I retrieve data in which part of this data is not needed.

Comment: ah I see. found something for this. Maybe next time you read the docu yourself? ;)

Comment: PiTheNumber is correct - You're saying you have a list of tags and want to get the posts that have those tags. So you can do this: `$p->where_related_tag('name', 'php')->or_where_related_tag('name', 'html')->get();`  -- this will give you all of the posts that have any of the tags that you use.

Comment: @swatkins I know PiTheNumber correct now, but my comment was before update